# Visual Studio does not deploy ASP.NET Core views when they are in an area

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, webdeploy, asp.net-mvc-areas, asp.net-mvc-views

#### Setup

- Visual Studio 2015 (with Update 3 and latest hotfix as of today)
- .NET Core SDK (preview 2) installed
- Create a new ASP.NET Core project
- Add a new area, register it and add views in it
- Deploy it to IIS using web deploy in Visual Studio

#### Part of my project.json

```
"publishOptions": {
  "include": [
    "wwwroot",
    "Views",
    "Areas/**/Views",
    "appsettings.json",
    "web.config"
  ]
},
```

#### My publish profile

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>MSDeploy</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>http://somedomain/</SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>False</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <PublishFramework>netcoreapp1.0</PublishFramework>
    <UsePowerShell>True</UsePowerShell>
    <EnableMSDeployAppOffline>True</EnableMSDeployAppOffline>
    <MSDeployServiceURL>http://someip</MSDeployServiceURL>
    <DeployIisAppPath>sitename</DeployIisAppPath>
    <RemoteSitePhysicalPath />
    <SkipExtraFilesOnServer>True</SkipExtraFilesOnServer>
    <MSDeployPublishMethod>RemoteAgent</MSDeployPublishMethod>
    <EnableMSDeployBackup>False</EnableMSDeployBackup>
    <UserName>username</UserName>
    <_SavePWD>True</_SavePWD>
    <PublishDatabaseSettings>
      <Objects xmlns="" />
    </PublishDatabaseSettings>
    <ADUsesOwinOrOpenIdConnect>False</ADUsesOwinOrOpenIdConnect>
    <AuthType>NTLM</AuthType>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

#### The problem

After successful deploy the area view are missing from the server. There is no `Area` folder nor the area's views are located in the `Views` folder. All other views (outside of areas) are present.

**Am I doing something wrong or this problem is known? Does anyone had the same problem and if so what is the solution?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Temporary fix as stated on https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4645 is to add

```
"**/*.cshtml",
```

in `publishOptions.include`.

Worked in my case.

Answer (score 1):

in the project.json file of your web app you need to tell it what to include:

```
"publishOptions": {
    "include": [
        "wwwroot",
        "Views",
        "Areas/**/Views",
        "appsettings.json",
        "navigation.xml",
        "web.config"
    ]
},
```

Comment: It is already there. I have this line: `"Areas/**/Views",` in my `publishOptions.include` in `project.json`.

Comment: Did you copy them over to the output directory? (under `buildOptions` in `copyToOutput`)

Answer (score 1):

I have found that webdeploy of ASP.NET applications using VS 2015 Update 3 to Azure does not correctly pick up all necessary files; specifically new Views, new fonts, and new CSS files that I have added to my project.

Manipulating the project Properties >> Package/Publish Web >> [Items to deploy] does not help - these new items are ignored.

Viewing my site and using the Chrome console, I noted the items that were missing, and edited the .csproj file to add the missing items; in my case:

```
<Content Include="Views\Dashboard\Index.cshtml" />
<Content Include="fonts\glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff" />
<Content Include="Content\jquery-confirm.min.css" />
```

in the obvious places - eg find other View files and intercalate mine.

I then found that Azure would pretend that *.woff files were missing (404). They were not, so I had to add the following to web.config:

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
        <mimeMap fileExtension="woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Poor show chaps.